# bundler failed to load command unicorn with mina deployment on digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, vps, digital-ocean

Deploying rails app with mina is showing this error.

```
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/kkteja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn)
Gem::LoadError: unicorn is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
  /home/kkteja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:322:in `block in replace_gem'
  /home/kkteja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn:22:in `<top (required)>'
```

when I run mina deploy, all the gems are getting installed but I dont see unicorn in it.

```
-----> Symlinking shared paths
-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
Using rake 11.1.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
Using arel 6.0.3
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using ionicons-rails 2.0.0
Using multi_json 1.12.0
Using pg 0.18.4
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.2
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using mime-types 3.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using sprockets 3.6.0
Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.2.5.1
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activemerchant 1.58.0
Using activemodel 4.2.5.1
Using jbuilder 2.4.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using activejob 4.2.5.1
Using activerecord 4.2.5.1
Using actionview 4.2.5.1
Using actionpack 4.2.5.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.5.1
Using railties 4.2.5.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using responders 2.1.1
Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
Using tinymce-rails 4.3.12
Using rails 4.2.5.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using devise 3.5.6
Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 61 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
-----> DB migrations unchanged; skipping DB migration
-----> Skipping asset precompilation
-----> Cleaning up old releases (keeping 5)
-----> Deploy finished
-----> Building
-----> Moving build to releases/31
-----> Build finished
-----> Launching
-----> Updating the current symlink
-----> Launching
-----> Starting Unicorn...
```

Thought something is wrong with the gem lock file, so I deleted it and ran `bundle install` command and then mina deployment. This is the gem lock file.

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemerchant (1.59.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.14, < 5.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2, < 4.0.0)
      i18n (>= 0.6.9)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)
    activemodel (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.5.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (9.0.5)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    connection_pool (2.2.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (4.1.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faker (1.6.3)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    ionicons-rails (2.0.0)
    jbuilder (2.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    kgio (2.10.0)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
     mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mina (0.3.8)
      open4 (~> 1.3.4)
      rake
    mina-sidekiq (0.4.0)
      mina
    mina-unicorn (0.4.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.0)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.8)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
      pkg-config (~> 1.1.7)
    open4 (1.3.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.18.4)
    pkg-config (1.1.7)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.5.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.5.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.16.0)
    rake (11.1.2)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.3.0)
    responders (2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)

    sidekiq (4.1.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
    spring (1.7.1)
    sprockets (3.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    tinymce-rails (4.3.12)
      railties (>= 3.1.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicorn (5.1.0)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activemerchant
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  faker
  ionicons-rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  mina
  mina-sidekiq
  mina-unicorn
  pg (~> 0.15)
  rails (= 4.2.5.1)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  sidekiq
  spring
  tinymce-rails
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unicorn
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

Have seen the content of `/home/kkteja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/unicorn` to check if something is missing there and this is how it looks.

```
#!/home/kkteja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'unicorn' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'unicorn', version
load Gem.bin_path('unicorn', 'unicorn', version)
```

Almost two days of research but still no luck. One beer for the geek who helps me to get along with this.

**ANSWER**
At-last after few days of digging, I found that the problem was with code being committed to repo. Mina fetches latest copy of the code from repo. I edited the gem file and added unicorn to it, but since it's not committed, when mina fetches the codebase and bundle installs it, unicorn is not found. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you use unicorn 4.9.0 and give it a try?

Comment: tried @KumarAbinash but the same output. When I run mina deploy I dont see unicorn under `-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler` section

Comment: Do you have more than one branch ?

Comment: Nope I have only master branch

Comment: I suggest you to set: branch, 'master' in your deploy.rb file and see if it works.

Comment: It's in fact there in he deploy.rb @ShyamBhimani

Comment: At-last after few days of digging, the problem was with code being committed to repo. Mina fetches latest copy of the code from repo. I edited the gem file and added unicorn to it, but since it's not committed, when mina fetches the codebase and bundle installs it, unicorn is not found. Hope this helps.